# Qt. Быстрый debug при нескольких поддиректориях

Tags: qt, qtcreator, qmake

Есть проект в таком виде:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
       qamqp_lib \
       vistool \
       tests \
...
```

Раньше, когда в окне creator было несколько проектов, я делал Set Active Project и дебажил через кнопку запуска. В случае наличия поддиректорий пункт set active project недоступен. При нажатии кнопки все равно запускается vistool, но я не уверен, что это определенное поведение.

В общем, каков аналог set active project в проекте из нескольких поддиректорий?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У QtCreator 4.3 назначение приложения для запуска находится в меню выбора режима сборки

[image: qtcreator subdir progect]